# Drush Core Update Failed in Docker

Tags: drush

I'm running a local dev Drupal 8 install in Docker using the Docker4Drupal project. I tried to run drush up to update my core from Drupal 8.2.4 to Drupal 8.2.6 and got the following errors:

```
rmdir(/var/www/html/aadlorg/drupal-8.2.6/core/lib): Directory not empty filesystem.inc:150                [warning]
Destination directory /var/www/html/aadlorg/drupal-8.2.6 already exists.                                    [error]
Updating project drupal failed. Attempting to roll back to previously installed version.                    [error]
rmdir(/var/www/html/aadlorg/drupal-8.2.6/core/modules): Directory not empty filesystem.inc:150            [warning]
Destination directory /var/www/html/aadlorg/drupal-8.2.6 already exists.                                    [error]
Unable to move /home/www-data/drush-backups/drupal/20170303142739/drupal to                                 [error]
/var/www/html/aadlorg/drupal-8.2.6.
Could not restore backup and rollback from failed upgrade. You will need to resolve manually.               [error]
Backups were restored successfully.                                                                            [ok]
Backups were restored successfully.                                                                            [ok]
require_once(/var/www/html/aadlorg/core/includes/errors.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or      [warning]
directory bootstrap.inc:562
[03-Mar-2017 14:32:40 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/aadlorg/core/includes/errors.inc' (include_path='.:') in /var/www/html/aadlorg/core/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 562
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/aadlorg/core/includes/errors.inc' (include_path='.:') in /var/www/html/aadlorg/core/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 562
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                          [error]
Error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/aadlorg/core/includes/errors.inc'
(include_path='.:') in /var/www/html/aadlorg/core/includes/bootstrap.inc, line 562
```

Now my Drupal install is totally broken:

```
Warning: require_once(autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/aadlorg/index.php on line 14

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in /var/www/html/aadlorg/index.php on line 14
```

I'm logged into the container as the www-data user and all the directories are owned by that user. So did I do something wrong? Should I try to run drush as root? Just not use drush to update core?

Answer (score 1):

Try using 2.0 version of docker4drupal, in the new version drush installed globally for www-data user to avoid potentials problems with permissions.